# NumPy vectorization along axis always possible?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a calculation to do along an axis of an NumPy array and I'd like to know if there is any way around a for-loop as this seems to be really slow. Normally I'm always trying to vectorize my code but with this calculation I just don't know how.

So let's say I have a 2d-array X with shape (7000 x 10). Like half of the entries are NaN values.
I'm now looking at every row of X (named x_i), which is a 1d-array with shape (10). Based on the indices of the non-NaN values in x_i, I'm partitioning a 1d-array M, shape (10), and a 2d-array C, shape (10 x 10). And then I'm doing some calculations with it and repeating everything along the first axis of X.

My code (pretty simplified) looks more or less like this:

```
X = np.random.random_sample((7000, 10))  # Note that in the real case, X also has a lot of NaN values
M = np.random.random_sample(10)
C = np.random.random_sample((10, 10))

Res = np.empty(X.shape[0])   # Preallocation of result

for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    # Get row i of X
    x_i = X[i]

    # Get indices of the non-NaN values in x_i
    index_not_nan_i = np.where(~np.isnan(x_i))[0]
    
    # Partition M and C according to indices
    M_i = M[index_not_nan_i]
    C_i = C[index_not_nan_i[..., None], index_not_nan_i]


    Res[i] = M_i @ C_i @ M_i
```

Example:

Let's say the first row of X looks like this x_i = [5, 3, 6, NaN, 7, NaN, NaN, 0, 5, NaN];
So index_not_nan_i = [0,1,2,4,7,8].
As there are 6 non-NaN values in x_i, M_i would be of shape (6) and C_i would be of shape (6,6).
The next x_i would of course have NaN-values at other positions, so index_not_nan_i would maybe be [3,7,5] and M_i and C_i would be of shape (3) and (3 x 3).

Are there any possibilities of vectorization?
I've already tried numpy.apply_along_axis(), but that just seems to be a regular for-loop in terms of performance. Also according to the documentation numpy.vectorize() just seems to be a for-loop as well, although I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: can M and C not be size and shape of X? Then just apply 2D mask ?

Comment: `numpy` doesn't have a tool to increase performance by simple wrapping.

Comment: @GhandiFloss Actually there is another dimension involved with size 19000. So C has actually shape 19000x10x10 and if I would broadcast it to match the shape of X, I would have a array of shape 7000x19000x10x10. And then I'm simply running out of memory.

Comment: Normal vectorization uses broadcasting and `axis` parameters to use the fast compiled code on higher dimension arrays.  `@` for example can do the `dot` product on `batches` (first dimensions).  But that may not be useful if your `M_i` and `C_i` differ in size depending on `i`.  In general 'vectorization' is hard when working with arrays that differ in size (where you can't make 3d+ arrays).

Comment: Can you convert X to 0 and 1 for NaN and not NaN. Then get your arrays by multiplication.